# Updating the main thread is not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, runnable

I just want to display the values of each iteration in the loop proceeded by 2 seconds delay.

when i run the code, the main thread freezes and after a while only the value of `tv_t1: 19` is displayed.

can anyone please let me know what is the error or what i am missing in the below posted code?

***NOTE*** :

I would like to do so on the main thread.

***Code**

```
tv_t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_t1);
    tv_t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_t2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tv_t1.setText("t1:" + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep on the UI Thread is a bad idea. Use an handler:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler():
private class MyRunnable implmenets Runanble {
   private final static int MAX_INT = 20;
   private int mCounter = 0;

         @Override
         public void run() {
         if (mCounter == 20) {
             mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
             return; 
         }
         mytexts.setText(" " + mCounter);
         mCounter++;
         mHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
     }
}
```

and in your create, after you initialze your views, call

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), 2000);
```

Comment: thank you, but i would like to do that on the main thread, can I

Comment: ok i undersatnd your code, but kndly would you please provide some explanation why the code i posted is not working? when i run it the screen displays nothinf and after a while it displays only "tv_1: 19"

Comment: the UI Thread is responsible to draw the views. if you make it sleep how it is supposed to draw?

Comment: ok, maybe after the sleep timer is over the ui thread continues to draw the view!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work out:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  tv_t1.setText("t1:" + i);
  }
}, 2000);
}
```

And yes if you get a delay when the value of "i" was 0 then set the first text outside the loop and start the loop with i=1 or put an if-else block inside the loop

Hope it helped.

Comment: thank you, but i would like to do that on the main thread, can I

Comment: did you tried running my answer? it's all main thread don't worry about that

Comment: ok i undersatnd your code, but kndly would you please provide some explanation why the code i posted is not working? when i run it the screen displays nothinf and after a while it displays only "tv_1: 19"

Comment: Just remember one thing dude, we never freeze the main thread, what i think is that the TextView takes some time to execute and display meanwhile the Main thread again goes to sleep and you are unable to see the result, when the last value is updated then only you are able to see the result

Comment: but i think after the sleep timer is finished, the ui thread should continue to draw the view!

Comment: i tried your code ,unfortunatey, it displays only the last value 19?

Comment: try to write one more line below the setText, i.e:

tv_t1.invalidate();

Comment: sometimes the view doesn't gets updated but the value is updated inside it, in those situations we do that

Answer (score 0):

`Thread` is Android's `main/UI` thread, and setting `sleep(value)` causes the main thread to sleep or
to stop doing its work for a scheduled time. If you want to update the `main UI` and `sleep` for a while, it is better to create a new `thread` and then create `Runnable` object that overrides `Run()`. And inside `Run()` you can call the function that is time consuming or also you can cause the new `thread` you created to `sleep` instead of forcing the `UI thread` to `sleep` which will cause all the main `UI` elements to freeze. The `Handler` in the below code works as intermediate between the `thread` and the `message queue`, you can also replace `h1` with your `tv_1` to post that as message into the queue and subsequently to update your view.

Please try the below code:

```
Handler h1 = new Handler();
Thread t1;

t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                loop();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();


    protected void loop() throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         t1.sleep(2000);
         h1.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv_t1.setText("tv_1: " + i);
            }
        });
     }
}
```